# how to parse individual invalid json obejcts to valid json and make a dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, key-value

how to parse an invalid JSON to valid JSON and make data frame which dynamically selects the keys as columns and values as rows in python. please help me out guys I tried in many different ways but still, I couldn't figure out.

```
data = c.execute("SELECT FRUITS .........FROM FOREST") #sql query 
output = (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
print(output)


output = {"a":"A","b":"B"}
         {"c":"C","d":"D"}

  #i may have many json objects
```

**output json is not a valid JSON because keys are hardcoded and no square 
brackets starting and ending and no commas after a JSON object, because of that I am not able to convert into data frames or anything

**how to convert the output into valid JSON and make a data frame like keys as columns and values as rows in python dynamically. I tried in many ways but didn't work please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear as to what exactly you are trying to do, but if your goal is to create a json structure from your sql query, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
output = df.to_json()
output = json.loads(output)
print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```

If you are able to read your table in to the data frame, it should output as valid json.

Comment: I am getting data from oracle database the output will be just rows so am hard coding the column names as keys and printing the rows as columns and due to the dattime formatting i am using output = (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)  that to get a string format json. but it getting the output as individual json objects with that i cannot do anything.@Jonathan please help me how to make valid json so that i can do dataframes

Comment: @sneharocckz - Can you pls edit your question description and include an example of `data` (header and first few rows), as well as clarify what you want in the output? Most sql clients already store the query results as some sort of key/value format which should be easy to convert to json